# Create a function that combines ggpredict dataframes from analyses in multiple imputation dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created ran multiple imputation for a mixed model analysis. I developed a ggpredict dataframe that plots all of the different results for the models fitted on each of the multiple imputed data. The problem is that I'd like to do this for 10 or 20 lmer results from these multiple imputations and could use some help building a function that would be capable of doing this.

Here's my code:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(mitml,stats,lme4,ggeffects, R2MLwiN, ggplot2)
data("JSPmiss")

#First running the multiple imputation

fml <- english + ravens + fluent ~ sex + (1|school)

JSPmiss <- within(JSPmiss, fluent <- factor(fluent))

imp <- jomoImpute(data = JSPmiss, formula = fml, n.burn = 1000, n.iter = 1000, m = 10,
                  seed = 1569)

imp.list <- mitmlComplete(imp, print = "all")

fit.imp <- with(imp.list, lmer(english ~ ravens + sex*fluent + (1|school)))

ggdf01.1 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[1]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.1$imp <- 1

ggdf01.1 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[1]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.1$imp <- 1

ggdf01.2 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[2]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.2$imp <- 2

ggdf01.3 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[3]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.3$imp <- 3

ggdf01.4 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[4]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.4$imp <- 4

ggdf01.5 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[5]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.5$imp <- 5

ggdf01.6 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[6]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.6$imp <- 6

ggdf01.7 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[7]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.7$imp <- 7

ggdf01.8 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[8]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.8$imp <- 8

ggdf01.9 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[9]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                      ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.9$imp <- 9

ggdf01.10 <- ggpredict(fit.imp[[10]], terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),
                       ci.lvl = 0.68)
ggdf01.10$imp <- 10

ggdf01 <- rbind(ggdf01.1, ggdf01.2, ggdf01.3, ggdf01.4, ggdf01.5, ggdf01.6, ggdf01.7, ggdf01.8, ggdf01.9, ggdf01.10)

fig30 <- ggplot(aes(x = x, y = predicted, group = imp), data =  ggdf01) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = imp), position = "identity", 
            size = 1) + 
  geom_ribbon(position = "identity", color = NA,
              aes(ymin = conf.low, 
                  ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.1) + 
  facet_grid(~group)

fig30
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of multiple near-identical lines of code, you can iterate through `fit.imp` using `lapply`, so your code simplifies to:

```r
pacman::p_load(mitml,stats,lme4,ggeffects, R2MLwiN, ggplot2, jomo, dplyr)

fml <- english + ravens + fluent ~ sex + (1|school)

JSPmiss <- within(JSPmiss, fluent <- factor(fluent))
imp <- jomoImpute(data = JSPmiss, formula = fml, n.burn = 1000, 
                  n.iter = 1000, m = 10, seed = 1569)

imp.list <- mitmlComplete(imp, print = "all")

fit.imp <- with(imp.list, lmer(english ~ ravens + sex*fluent + (1|school)))

bind_rows(lapply(fit.imp, function(x) {
   ggpredict(x, terms = c("fluent[all]", "sex"),ci.lvl = 0.68)
}), .id = "imp") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = predicted, group = imp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = imp), position = "identity", 
            size = 1) + 
  geom_ribbon(position = "identity", color = NA,
              aes(ymin = conf.low, 
                  ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.1) + 
  facet_grid(~group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>